# simplify with law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

set $S_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$. Determine
$$
\frac{E\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-S_{n})^{2}\big)}{Var(S_{n})}.
$$
and I used law of large numbers to approach it

Since $S_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is an i.i.d sequence, from strong law of large numbers, we have  $S_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\to E(X_1)$. And with the properties of expectations,
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{E\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-S_{n})^{2}\big)}{Var(S_{n})} \\
=&\frac{E\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-S_{n})^{2}\big)}{E(S^2_n)-E(S_n)^2} \\
=&\frac{E\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-E(X_1))^{2}\big)}{E(X_1^2)-E(X_1)^{2}}
\end{align*}
what further steps should I take?

Comment: $E(S_n^2)\neq E(X_1^2)$. Use properties of variance in denominator and simplify the sum in numerator first. Look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance